# Tracing syscalls of chromium or setting chromium configuration

Tags: chrome, strace

Given complex application like for example chromium, does anyone now convenient (and actually working) method of tracing it's syscalls?

#### What i am doing

Starting chromium in temporary profile but with several extensions enabled, like ghostery (and several others but one is enough to test)
`chromium-browser --temp-profile --enable-plugins --no-first-run --disable-first-run-ui --no-default-browser-check --load-extension=/home/MYPROFILE/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions/mlomiejdfkolichcflejclcbmpeaniij/3.1.48_0`

#### What i want to do

I want to know when, and from which file does chromium run start pages that are created/launched on first run by extensions. Each time chromium runs that temporary profile Ghostery opens two start pages - surveymonkey and it's configuration. Some other extensions do that too.
I want that gone :) so I'd be happy with any solution, editing configuration etc.

#### What i tried

1. I've checked [commandline switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches) if there is any that could prevent opening any pages by extensions during chromium startup, but I haven't found any.
2. I've checked that chromium extensions in theirs `manifest.json` have options.html page, which supposedly is run on first run. I've removed this json entry, yet pages still appeared.
3. I've tried to strace chromium process, using:
   a) $ `strace -F -v -o "/tmp/chromium_run_<backtick>date +%F_%T<backtick>" chromium-browser --temp-profile --enable-plugins --no-first-run --disable-first-run-ui --no-default-browser-check --load-extension=/home/MYPROFILE/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions/mlomiejdfkolichcflejclcbmpeaniij/3.1.48_0` but chromium sandbox was fighting back, saying something like

   Using PPAPI flash.
   The setuid sandbox is not running as root. Common causes:

   - An unprivileged process using ptrace on it, like a debugger.
   - A parent process set prctl(PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS, ...)
     Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Operation not permitted

   b) $ sudo `strace -F -v -o "/tmp/chromium_run_<backtick>date +%F_%T<backtick>" chromium-browser --temp-profile --enable-plugins --no-first-run --disable-first-run-ui --no-default-browser-check --load-extension=/home/MYPROFILE/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions/mlomiejdfkolichcflejclcbmpeaniij/3.1.48_0` threw no errors, but after several hundred kilobytes of log there was no `open` or anything on file i was expecting, nor chromium application window appeared as well, it hanged somewhere ( `waitpid(3,` ).

Any other ideas that come to my mind are both time consuming

- groking chromium sources to find guilty line
- setting up chromium build locally and build chromium myself, with symbols and have a try with gdb.

I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: investigate dtrace or sysdig

Comment: Well, I suppose `perf` could do too, but this is like using a cannon to kill a fly...

Comment: Does your chromium support the `--no-sandbox` option?

Comment: You could also try running the strace as root. That way it likely won't disable setuid programs. Something like `strace -yourstraceoptions su youruid chromium -yourchromiumoptions`

Comment: Well, funny - chromium said "using not supported flag --no-sandbox" which clearly states that it **is** supported :) with no-sandbox it started - leaving nice 52MB log to check. Regarding second comment - in point b) I've tried running `sudo strace -straceflags chromium -chromiumflags` but chromium didn't even start.